# Syncing List with another List containing Some data C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

Using winforms, Visual Studio 2013 Community, C#.

I need to sync the order of two Lists. One of the lists contains an index, the other contains the selections out of that index.

Example:
List 1 contains:

```
[0]Data0
[1]Data1
[2]Data2
[3]Data3
[4]Data4
[5]Data5
```

And List 2 Contains Some of that data But In a different Order:

```
[0]Data3
[1]Data1
[2]Data5
```

I need some way to Get the Orders to match up so that List 2 looks like this:

```
[0]Data1
[1]Data3
[2]Data5
```

Example Code:

```
public List<string> lista = new List<string>();
public List<string> listb = new List<string>();

public void fillListA(string mockstring)
{
    for(i=0;i<750000;i++)//just to give Idea of the number of Strings in the List
    {
        lista.add(mockstring + i.ToString());//Fill List with data
    }
}
OnClickEventHappens(string SelectedFromListA)//Mock event that fires if The user clicks on a string in ListA (As its displayed in a label on form1)
{
    if(listb.Contains(SelectedFromListA))        
    {
        listb.Remove(SelectedFromListA);
    }
    else
    {
        listb.Add(SelectedFromListA);    
    }    
}
```

By Doing the Above Since the user can click on Any "string" that is in lista at any point, listb ends up completely unorganized. (since you can "click" lista[5],lista[1] and that there is enough to mix up the order)

I don't want to iterate everytime It changes either (Listb is displayed on a different tab so I can sort it then before its displayed, but it would be nice to keep it synced in smaller pieces rather then looping the entire lists)

The Order I need to keep them in is the order that Lista has "strings" added to it. (Which I currently do by hand with Inserts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<string> orderedlistb = lista.Intersect(listb).ToList()
```

This will iterate `lista`, creating a new list of all of the elements in `lista` that also occur in `listb`.

In general when you do this, you will need to ensure that the objects that you are comparing are either reference equal or you have properly overridden `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(Object)` for those objects.

In this case, since you are just using strings, you don't need to worry about this.

Comment: the lists are really just strings, Does Intersect modify lista or return a list? (eg could I do `listb = lista.intersect(listb).ToList()`?

Comment: @JasonBrown it returns a new List.  You could indeed assign the result of that to `listb` if you wished.